# Tabbed InfoWindow Google Maps API v3 using a KML layer

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am attempting to add tabs to the infowindow of this site http://nctcog.org/trans/data/trafficcounts/index.asp

As I have literally thousands of points stored in a database, as the map center changes, I grab the map boundaries and pass them to a page that build the KML file which then loads them using google.maps.KmlLayer.  Most of the data in the infowindow is stored in the same table as the lat,lon and I load it along with the coordinates when I build the KML file.

I have tried several methods of manipulating the  tag with no success.

I know there is a listener that can be added to manipulate the infowindow, but since I'm not adding my markers with a listener, how do I tie it to the correct marker?

Comment: It sounds like you have two questions: 1. add tabs and 2. assigning InfoWindow to a marker. Are they related somehow?

Comment: I guess so since it appears the only way to implement a tabbed window is through a listener event.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is manipulating your markers from a KML file. As far as I have tried, there's no way to do so when you are using KMLayer. Since you are creating KML on the fly, it makes things easier.

Luckily :) I worked on a KML question recently and have a starter file. An annoying "feature" is that the AJAX calls forced me to put the HTML and KML in the same public computer. I couldn't work offline. You could try a local web server, I didn't.

https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/kmlcircle.html

The key idea is to replace the default functionality of `createMarker` shown below with the name of your own function. In this case I was adding circles, in yours, you need to add InfoWindows.

```
    geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
      map: map, 
      createMarker: addCircle});
```

Adding tabs to your infowindow can be done in at least two ways. The [JQuery way](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html) and [Tabber Way](http://www.grasoft.be/mtb/tracks/ShowGPX.htm?gpx=20100523.gpx) (once this page is loaded click on the green line)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, by passing "placemark" to your AddCircle function, it gains access to all of the child elements which is how you can make the placemark.StyleUrl assignment.  By that logic I could go up one level and pass in "document"  and give myself access to the <style> node as well so I can set my custom markers correctly. I won't be able to start playing with this until Monday, but this definitely looks it is sending me in the right direction.

Comment: The way I used `placemark` was to simply iterate through the <Placemark> elements of the KML. I don't even know how to go up a level to <Document>. I copied the docs example. `placemark` appeared as the standard variable. http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage